# How can I peek nextInt from InputStream?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

In the below code, userInput is not the same as the value that determines `input.nextInt() <= 100.`

```
`while (input.nextInt() <= 100)    
{    
     System.out.println("larger than 100 please");
     input.nextLine();
}
userInput = input.nextInt();`
```

I know there's other ways like the following,

`do {
userInput = input.nextInt();
}while (input.nextInt() <= 100)`

Is it possible for vaiable userInput to read the same value as the one used in the previous logical decision?

Comment: Have you considered storing in a variable?

Comment: We have no way of knowing what the type of variable `input` is. Could you include some more code for context? At least the declaration and instantiation of `input`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you looking for something like this?

```
while ((userInput = input.nextInt()) <= 100)    
{    
    System.out.println("larger than 100 please");
}//end while
```

Comment: assign value to userInput while logic decision? I tested and there's an error:incompatible types.

Comment: @user2820393 did you put `()` around your assignment statement?